# AmCharts - set max value axis using dataprovider

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to set max value axis using dataprovider, since I'm dynamically loading data in my bar chart I need to see the "progress" on one of the bars compared to the one that is supposed to be the total.

How do I achieve this?

I' tried with:

```
"valueAxes": [
                {
                    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                    "stackType": "regular",
                    "maximum": myDataProviderAttribute
                }
```

But no luck.

Any suggestion will be much apreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your method of "dynamically loading data" in your bar chart is. If you're using the dataLoader plugin, you might want to add a listener to the `dataUpdated` event and update the maximum of your first value axis depending on the data that you've received. If you're using AJAX, you can choose to build your chart after you've received the response. If you can share how you get your data, I could give you better advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've submited a ticket to AmCharts support and got this feedback:

You can set max before the chart is initialized based on the data you have, inside addInitHandler. Here is an example for a simple column chart:

```
AmCharts.addInitHandler(function(chart) {

  // find data maximum:
  var min = chart.dataProvider[0].visits;
  for (var i in chart.dataProvider) {
    if (chart.dataProvider[i].visits > max) {
        max = chart.dataProvider[i].visits;
    }
  }
  // set axes max based on value above:
  chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = max  + 100;
  chart.valueAxes[0].strictMinMax = true;
});
```

You may need to use strictMinMax as above to enforce the value:
https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#strictMinMax

Example of setting minimum inside addInitHandler:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/b4be8cb4e3c073909860720e0909a876?editors=1010

If you refresh the data, or use live data, then before you animate or validate the chart to show the updated data, you should recalculate the max and, if you want the axis to change then use chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = max; where max is something you calculate based on data input.

Here is an example:

```
function loop() {
    var data = generateChartData();
    chart.valueAxes[0].maximum = max;

    // refresh data:
    chart.animateData(data, {
        duration: 1000,
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(loop, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

The lines above were used in this example:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d0d5d03cfdcc2cc256e28ec52ad8b95c/?editors=1010